# Are the high-order bits of $n^2$ as likely to be zeroes as ones?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

Let $B_i(n)$ be the $i$th bit in the binary expansion of $n$, so that $n=\sum B_i(n)2^i$. Now let $n$ be randomly and uniformly chosen from some large range, and let  $E(j)$ be the expected value of $B_j\bigl(n^2\bigr)$, the $j$th bit in the expansion of $n^2$.  That is:

$$E(j) = \lim_{M\to\infty} \frac1M \sum_{n=0}^{M-1}B_j\bigl(n^2\bigr)$$

if this limit exists. It is not hard to see that it must exist for any fixed $j$, since the function $B_j\bigl(n^2\bigr)$ is completely determined by the value of $n\bmod 2^{j+1}$, and so is periodic with period at most $2^{j+1}$. In fact we can get rid of the limit:

$$E(j) = \frac1{2^{j+1}} \sum_{n=0}^{2^{j+1}-1}B_j\bigl(n^2\bigr)$$

For example, the first few values of $E$ are $\frac12, 0, \frac14, \frac14$.

Numerical evidence suggests that:

> $$\lim_{j\to\infty} E(j) = \frac12$$

Is this true?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\sum_{i} B_j(i^2)$. You are going to bump up against the idea that this isn't an actual probability, but rather a relative density.

Comment: You actually only need the range $i=0,\dots,2^j-1$ since $(n+2^j)^2$ has the same $j$th binary bit as $n^2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, I think I've fixed the indices.

Comment: [This fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Pairs_of_residues_and_nonresidues) about the distribution of pairs of successive quadratic residues and non-residues modulo odd primes may or may not be of interest; if something similar were to hold modulo powers of $2$, your limit would follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to "[Distribution of the figures 0 and 1 in the various orders of binary representation of kth powers of integers](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-102/S0025-5718-1968-0225714-8/S0025-5718-1968-0225714-8.pdf)", W. Gross and R. Vacca (*Mathematics of Computation*, April 1968, **22**, #102, 423–427), the answer is **yes**.

On page 423 they define a function $N_k(h)$, which is the count of 1 bits in the $h$th position of the sequence $n^k$ over one of its periods, so my $E(j)$ is exactly $N_2(j)2^{-(j+1)}$.  They then show (page 424) that

$$E(j) = \frac12\left(1 - 2^{-\lfloor j/2\rfloor}\right)$$

except for $j=0$.  A similar result holds for arbitrary $k$th powers—the density of high-order bits approaches $\frac12$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 2):

By [Hensel's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma), you can show that the nonzero squares in the $2$-adics $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$ are exactly the numbers of the form $4^n(8k+1)$ : the numbers whose binary expansion ends with "001" and an even number of zeroes.

The squares mod $2^j$ are again those numbers. 
Thus, the number of squares modulo $2^j$ is $1 + 2^{j-3} + 2^{j-5} + \ldots \approx 2^{j-1}/3$.
Out of those squares, those where flipping the $2^{j-1}$ bit doesn't result again in a square are either $0$ or $2^{2k}$ with $j \le 2k+3$, so they are at most $3$, which is negligible compared to all the other squares.